# add a timeout arround a javascript snippet

Tags: javascript

I am often running into problems with third party tracking.
Since they slowing down the page from time to time I am looking for a solution.

My idea is to have a timeout arround the snippet itself. To avoid extending page load times. If the answer or the compiling takes to long it would be ok to cancel the whole block.

This is an example of a third party implemantation:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _spef = _spef || [];
    _spef.push(["enableLinkTracking"]);
    _spef.push(["trackPageView"]);
    (function () {
        var u = "//trck.spoteffects.net/analytics/";
        _spef.push(['setTrackerUrl', u + 'piwik.php']);
        _spef.push(['setSiteId','XXXXXXX']);
        var d = document, g = d.createElement("script"), s = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        g.type = "text/javascript";
        g.defer = true;
        g.async = true;
        g.src = u + "spef.min.js";
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
    })();
</script>
```

But I am not sure what can I put arround a snippet like this. Maybe you can help me out :)

Comment: Put that code in external JS file and include in ur page with attribute `defer` on `<script>` tag so this script will be executed after the page load is done

Comment: This isn't going to work. Fix the underlying problem, i.e. the slow "tracking code". Trying to make it "time out" whatever that means is going to be a waste of time.

Comment: @UsmanWali that will make zero difference. The code is still executed on the main thread, the load of the js **file** is just deffered. It's still not async

Comment: JS doesn't have any way to interrupt synchronous code, AFAIK.

Comment: @Barmar is right. If the code "making it slow" is because it's blocking, you can't unblock it. Setting a timeout just makes it happen a little later, it'll still block and it'll still "slow down your page". Javascript is (mostly) single threaded a timeout just means the processing is deffered, it's not on a different thread, it's on the same thread

Comment: Why don't you just use Google analytics for your "tracking" it's a tried and trusted solution that won't suffer from these issues?

Answer (score -1):

You could put this around it, but it will just defer the slow loading by a second, and not sure if it is allowed by spoteffects rules:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function spef() {
        //put 3rd party code here (what is between script tags)
    }

    setTimeout(spef, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: this will still "Slow down the page" the slowness will just happen 1 seconds later